# Как узнать получил клиент данные от сервер через UDP?

Tags: c++, udp

Я использую

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
```

У меня есть сервер и есть клиенты, сервер принимает UDP запросы.

Я отправлю запросы от клиента серверу, сервер отдает ответ.
Как определить, клиент получил или не получил ответ от сервера.

Сейчас я думаю над двумя вариантами:

1. клиент сам должен об этом сообщить серверу.
2. сервер должен сам проверить клиента.

Представьте гоночную трассу, два квадрата(клиент) соревнуются кто первый, они оба отправляют запросы на сервер, сервер выдает ответ.

Теперь один квадрат отправляет запрос серверу и сообщает место положение. сервер отсылает ответ что он попал под препятствие, то есть врезался но клиент не получил эти данные и потерял.

Отсылает снова запрос о место положении, сервер отсылает ему новые данные и когда клиент их получает он понимает что его телепортирует, возможно вы видели такое в GTA 5

Что бы это избежать, сервер должен отсылал старые данные, тогда клиент плавно получит данные о препятствие и обработает ситуацию столкновения.

Comment: Проще перейти на TCP :) А вообще UDP - без гарантии доставки, так что сервер сам, без помощи клиента, доставку не проверит.

Comment: TCP не подойдет, он медленный, мне нужно что бы клиент получал всегда новые данные, но если я смогу проверить что клиент потерял данные, сервер смог бы отправить несколько пакетов сразу. (1-й пакет, старые денные) (2-рой пакет новые данные)

Comment: @tramp в током случае удачи с реализацией: вам придется самостоятельно решать вопросы утери пакета, порядка поступления пакетов, ужимать сообщения в 1500 байт (включая заголовки) и т.д.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я же надеюсь не первый кто столкнулся с такой проблемой и кто то это уже делал.
Что бы мне не пилить велосипед, я бы хотел посмотреть у других.

Comment: tcp не медленный:) но если очень очень хочется и того, и другого, есть [sctp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCTP) - это upd+tcp  в одном пакете. Правда под виндой его не подвезли, а в Линуксе из коробки. Но есть реализации.

Comment: @KoVadim не таких штук мне не надо, в гебридах много кода будет, я устану разбираться.

Comment: @tramp ну вот вы странный: мне нужен велосипед udp_как_tcp, tcp пользоваться не хочу, свой пилить тоже не хочу, готовую реализацию такого велосипеда использовать тоже не хочу...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch :) не я не это хотел сказать, я хочу велосипед кодовый, и не против, но главное что бы не гибрид, если это будет только работать через udp то супер.
но если там связка udp и tcp я не согласен с этим.

Comment: Почитайте как TCP устроен. Вам надо будет что то подобное реализовать на UDP. Можно немного по другому, но идеи примерно те же использовать. Клиент должен сообщать серверу что он видел, а сервер принимать решение, что следует переотправить. Проблема только в том, что на это все уходит время. Сервер перед попыткой переотправки должен какое то время подождать. За это время наверняка уже произойдут какие то новые события. И в итоге выйдет, что сервер конечно гарантированно сообщил о столкновении, но уже после того как клиент проехал еще полтрассы. выйдет телепортация назад

Comment: @tramp как всегда, не читал, но осуждаю. sctp - это отдельно лежащий протокол, на том же уровне, что и tcp/udp. В винде обычно делают через udp.

Comment: Собственно вы считаете TCP медленным именно потому, что он пытается повторно доставлять при ошибках. Пока ошибок нет - он очень быстрый, но любая ошибка понятное дело приостанавливает поток. Какой бы алгоритм на UDP вы ни реализовали для подтверждения доставки, вы придете к тем же проблемам. Вопрос только в том, что можно сделать что бы проблемы проявлялись несколько по иному и выбрать какой вид глюков вы можете себе позволить

Comment: IMHO если делать заточку "как в TCP" под UDP для реализации своего протокола более высокого уровня, то оптимизации скорости будет с гулькин нос. Игра не стоит свеч (ну, разве что, с образовательной целью), лучше взять TCP. IMHO, конечно

Comment: Если кто то знаете протокол под windows то конечно скидывайте ссылку.
Я сам не против лишний раз не велосипедить, особенно если уже есть готовые решение на github

Comment: так она уже есть на странице википедии. Но если не получается найти, то вот к примеру http://www.sctp.de/sctp-download.html

Comment: @KoVadim не я не это имел введу, по названию я сам могу найти, я хотел сказать что если кто то знает хороший репозиторий с UDP реализацией для игр например. То может скинуть ссылку.

Comment: ок, подождем:) может действительно есть.

Comment: Ну посмотрите, например, как реализован tftp - он на базе udp. Я имею в виду - как реализована проверка доставки пакетов клиенту (описание подтверждения доставки). Но такой вопрос - почему вы уверены в медленности tcp? Вы уже написали с ним и убедились, что именно это - слабое место?..

Comment: @Harry да я попробовал TCP слабое место находиться где подключение идет клиента к серверу, если подключение обрывается серверу нужно время, а клиент зависает ожидая пакетов от сервера, но их нету и не будет, потому что нужно заново переподключиться.

Comment: Еще я проверял нагрузку на сервер, сделал его слабым и ддосил пакетами / подключением через клиентов. В какой то момент TCP сервер зависал и отказывался перезапускать по нужному порту.

Comment: а вот с UDP все интересней, сервер не падал но пакеты шли с задержкой, если задержка увеличивалась, то пакеты терялись где то по пути.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте пакетам порядковые номера. Если номера идут не подряд, то пакеты с выпавшими номерами потерялись.